# EasyMock with withConstructor ignoring addMockedMethod called within constructor

Tags: java, easymock

I want to test a method of a class. 
For that I need to mock another method of the class, which is been called from the constructor. 
Also I've to pass mocked object to the constructor. 
When I'm not using withConstructor, it is picking addMockedMethod correctly. 
But whenever I'm using withConstructor, it is not using the method passed in addMockedMethod anymore. (getting the exception for the following code)
Is there anything I can do here to solve this? Following is the code

Main Class:

```
public class A {
   B b;
   C c;
   public A (B _b) {
      b = _b;
      c = getC();
   }
   public void run (String _val) {
     String val = b.getValue();
     //do something
   }
   public static C getC() {
     StaticD.getC();
   }
}
public class StaticD {
   public static C getC() {
      throw new RuntimeException("error");
   }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@Test(testName = "ATest")
public class ATest  extends EasyMockSupport {
  public void testRun() {
     B bMock = createMock(B.class);
     expect(bMock.getValue()).andReturn("test");
     replayAll();
     A obj = createMockBuilder(A.class).
        addMockedMethod("getC").
        withConstructor(bMock).
        createMock();
     obj.run();
     verifyAll();
     resetAll();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking the `getC()` method within the `A` class when it is called during instantiation is never going to work with just EasyMock. You're basically trying to call a method on an object before it has been created, so it can't work.

Having said that, PowerMock is your friend here. PowerMock has the ability to mock methods that EasyMock cannot. In your example here, PowerMocks ability to mock static methods will help a lot.

Here's a sample test I put together for your case that will allow you to create your test. It also allows you to create a real `A` object as you're not trying to mock any of it's methods any more.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) //Tells the class to use PowerMock
@PrepareForTest(StaticD.class) //Prepares the class you want to use PowerMock on
public class ATest extends EasyMockSupport {

    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        final B bMock = createMock(B.class);
        final C cMock = createMock(C.class);

        PowerMock.mockStatic(StaticD.class); //Makes all the static methods of this class available for mocking
        EasyMock.expect(StaticD.getC()).andReturn(cMock); //Adds the expected behaviour
        PowerMock.replay(StaticD.class); //PowerMock to replay the static class

        final A aReal = new A(bMock);

        EasyMock.expect( bMock.getValue() ).andReturn("test");
        replayAll();

        aReal.run("test");

        verifyAll();
        resetAll();
    }
}
```

The version of PowerMock needed depends on the version of JUnit you're using, but all of these sorts of things are covered at the [PowerMock Home Page](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/)